# IncompatibleClassChangeError Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, pojo

I'm using `OpenPojo` for validating getter and setter methods of a class.
But while trying to validate my getter and setter methods I'm having following exception:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.openpojo.reflection.java.bytecode.asm.SubClassCreator has
> interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

Here is my code:

```
public final class ClientToken implements RememberMeAuthenticationToken {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3141878022445836151L;

private final String clientName;

private final Credentials credentials;

private String userId;

private boolean isRememberMe;

public ClientToken(final String clientName, final Credentials credentials) {
    this.clientName = clientName;
    this.credentials = credentials;
}

public void setUserId(final String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public void setRememberMe(boolean isRememberMe) {
    this.isRememberMe = isRememberMe;
}

public String getClientName() {
    return this.clientName;
}

public Object getCredentials() {
    return this.credentials;
}

public Object getPrincipal() {
    return this.userId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return CommonHelper.toString(ClientToken.class, "clientName", this.clientName, "credentials", this.credentials,
            "userId", this.userId);
}

public boolean isRememberMe() {
    return isRememberMe;
}
}
```

Does anybody help me why this problem occurs.

Comment: Please show us the complete (unedited) stacktrace.

Comment: Also, please show us the code or configs where you are using OpenPOJO.  Because the exception doesn't appear to be related to the code that you showed us.